# Python socket - connected socket

Tags: python

I'm currently coding a socket server in Python (VS2012 addon)
But I'm stuck and can't get a new socket from an accepted connection.

```
while (True):
    new = sock.accept()

    acc_addr = new[1]
    ip = acc_addr[0]
    connid = acc_addr[1]

    print 'Received connection from ' + ip + ':' + connid.__str__()
```

This is what I use, but now I want a new socket() instance for the connected user for my other class (for receiving, sending etc), but how would I get the new socket() instance?

Comment: I do it on VS2012 but I didn't notice it wouldn't be indented at the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `new` tuple returned by [`accept()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.accept) has 2 elements: at `[1]`, there is the address tuple, consisting of the `ip` and the port (named `connid` by you) - and at `0` there is a socket object which can be used for communicating with the client.

So just do `clsock = new[0]` and you have your `socket()` instance.